# Does AdSense penalise AI generated content

Tags: google-adsense

As per title: is AdSense able to detect AI generated content and will it use this information to determine if a website is eligible for its program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AdSense approval is a manual process so it really depends on the reviewer.

There would be too many false positives if they tried to determine if content was written by GPT.

The reviewers are mostly concerned that your site is following guidelines. No deceptive layouts. No posting of copyrighted material or other things that break the ToS like pornography, drugs, violence. Ensuring you have meta pages such as Privacy Policy, Terms and Conditions, Contact Us. That the layout, navigation, and presentation is professional.